# Where can I find any documentation regarding the "srcDir" property?

Tags: gradle

I created a build.gradle file in which we have:

```
apply plugin: "java"

sourceSets{
    main{
        java{
            srcDir "another/source/folder"
        }
    }
}
```

and it does what I expect: it uses also the Java classes defined in that folder to create the Java class files.
Browsing I saw that most of the example use `srcDirs`, which does its job as well, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html).
But in the documentation I cannot see any trace of the `srcDir` property, there is only the `srcDirs` (plural).
Is there another place I can look for in?

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.file.SourceDirectorySet.html

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I was looking at the wrong documentation, basically.